# Symfony forward form submission

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Hello I'm having the following problem, I tried to follow this question's answer on how to do a form over many pages. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254733/how-to-split-long-symfony-form-in-multiple-pages)

I made the following controller for the first form

```
public function reportarSeguimientoAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $seguimiento = new Seguimiento();


    $form = $this->createForm(SeguimientoType::class, $seguimiento);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $seguimiento = $form->getData();

        if($seguimiento->getAsistencia() == 1)
        {
            $response = $this->forward('AppBundle:Counselor:seguimientoDos', array(
                    'seguimiento' => $seguimiento,
            ));
            return $response;
        }
        else
        {
            $em->persist($seguimiento);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('success');
        }
    }

return $this->render('default/crearSeguimiento.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

This redirects me to the second part of the form in case that a field is filled, it does not change the url though.

```
    public function seguimientoDosAction(Request $request, $seguimiento)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(SeguimientoAsistioType::class, $seguimiento);
    $form->handleRequest($Request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $seguimiento = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($seguimiento);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('success');
    }

    return $this->render('default/crearSeguimiento.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

The appearance of the page does change yet it doesn't submit when clicking the submit button in the second form it just renders the first part of the form, it marks the first one as submitted. I'm guessing it has to do with it not being a redirection but I can't seem to be able to redirect passing the $seguimiento variable which contains the first part of the form to submit.

Any solution to either passing the variable on a redirect or submitting the second form is really welcome.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution ?

Comment: For this project, I did a workaround by separating the entity into one for every page. What I recommend is learning more PHP and doing the form's logic by hand rather than using the form generator, it's actually not that hard but it does take some practice to get it right.